# Is it possible to associate a key that is associated with a built in command with my own command?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, command

The WPF DataGrid has a built-in Delete command, triggered by the Del key. However, I have written my own implementation of a command that deletes rows from the DataGrid and updates the underlying model. I still would like this custom command to be triggered by the Del key.

I tried to accomplish this with:

```
 <Grid.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding MyOwnDeleteCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myDataGrid,Path= SelectedItems}"
                Key="Delete"/>
 </Grid.InputBindings>
```

But this fails. It does work when I add a `Modifiers="Shift"` attribute.

The only way of getting it work for the Del key seems subscribing to the KeyDown event of the DataGrid. But is it possible to bind my custom command to the Del key directly?

Comment: have you tried setting `CanUserDeleteRows="False"` on the DataGrid since you are using a `KeyBinding` to perform delete actions?

Comment: @sa_ddam Yes, I have done so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is shamingly simple: Just repeat the Keybinding of the UserControl on the Datagrid!
I also found that you can set a Keybinding to 'ApplicationCommands.NotACommand to disable a gesture that is built-in in a Control.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could disable deleting on the `DataGrid` since you are handling the logic in your own `Command` via `KeyBinding`

```
<DataGrid CanUserDeleteRows="False"  ....../>
```

### Edit:

Not sure if using a [RoutedCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752070.aspx) will fit your pattern, but you could route the command from the DataGrid and handle your logic there.

```
<DataGrid.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="DataGrid.DeleteCommand" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
</DataGrid.CommandBindings>
```

Comment: Curiously, if I look at other questions on SO, this seems to work. Not here though... Any other valid shortcut key works, Del excepted.